# how do they return same result?

Tags: php, mysqli

Here, `$user_id` is single quoted:

```
$select = $conn->query("SELECT firstname,lastname FROM users WHERE user_id = '$user_id'");
$row = $select->fetch_assoc();
    print_r($row);
```

Here, `$user_id` is not single quoted

```
$select = $conn->query("SELECT firstname,lastname FROM users WHERE user_id = $user_id");
$row = $select->fetch_assoc();
    print_r($row);
```

If `$user_id = 1`, does `'1' == 1`?? Both return associative array of `$user_id = 1`.

Comment: because, MySQL is forgiving when it comes to quoted integers. Had that variable been a string, it would be a different story. This being *"the short answer"*. So now you know.

Comment: ... dary!  (oh wait, that's from something else).

Comment: I've been waiting for 5 minutes already!

Comment: @AbraCadaver Really? I was here a minute sooner then.

Comment: Answered in more ways than one.

Answer (score 0):

For your use case, yes, `'1' == 1`.

[From the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html):

> To cast a string to a numeric value in numeric context, **you normally do not have to do anything** other than to use the string value as though it were a number:
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT 1+'1';
>        -> 2
> ```